# Enunciate not working with Generics

Tags: java, json, generics, jax-rs, enunciate

My resource is

```
@GET
@Path("/items")
public MyCollection<Items> getItems()throws Exception{
   //Code to return MyCollection<items>
}
```

My Item class is

```
   @XmlRootElement
   public class Item{
       private int id;
       private String name;
       //Have getters and Setters.
   }
```

And My collection class is Generic as below.

```
 public class MyCollection<T> extends MyBaseCollection{
     private java.util.Collection<T> items;
     private int count;
 }
```

When i try to generate doc using enunciate. The sample Json has only the item and count and the fields of Item class is not getting reflected.

My sample Json generated is

```
      {
    "items" : [ {
    }, {
    }, {
    }, {
    }, {
    }, {
    }, {
    }, {
    } ],
    "count" : ...,
  }
```

How to get id,name inside the Item in the generated sample Json?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation that i have run into as well, there is no way to specify @TypeHint on a nested object. To support documentation, consider creating a custom collection that defines "items" as a collection of specific class instead of generic.

If you have an idea of how you would want this to work (using the generic type) I suggest submitting enhancement request to Enunciate team.

I have a similar problem where I am returning a Map and I can't @TypeHint this.